# Is it possible to combine .agg(dictionary) and renaming the resulting column with .alias() in Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, aggregate

I have a pyspark dataframe 'pyspark_df'  I want to group the data and aggregate the data with a general function string name like one of the following :'avg', 'count', 'max', 'mean', 'min', or 'sum'.

I need the resulting aggregated name to be 'aggregated' regardless of the aggregation type.
I have been able to do this as follows.

```
seriesname = 'Group'
dateVar = 'as_of_date'
aggSeriesName = 'Balance'
aggType = 'sum'
name_to_be_Changed = aggType + '(' + aggSeriesName + ')' 
group_sorted = pyspark_df.groupby(dateVar,seriesname).agg({aggSeriesName: aggType}).withColumnRenamed(name_to_be_Changed,'aggregated').toPandas()
```

However, is there a way to do this via .alias()?  I have seen this used as follows

```
group_sorted = pyspark_df.groupby(dateVar,seriesname).agg(sum(aggSeriesName).alias('aggregated')).toPandas()
```

How do I use alias in a way that I don't have to type out the 'sum(aggSeriesName)' portion?  Hopefully I am being clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are asking this question and can't therefore provide a proper alternative solution. As far as I know it is not possible to combine `.agg(dictionary)` and renaming the resulting column with `.alias`. `withColumnRenamed` is the way to go for this case.

What you also can do is applying a [selectExpr](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.selectExpr):

```py
vertices = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
  ("a", "Alice", 34),
  ("b", "Bob", 36),
  ("c", "Charlie", 30),
  ("d", "David", 29),
  ("e", "Esther", 32),
  ("f", "Fanny", 36),
  ("g", "Gabby", 60)], ["id", "name", "age"])

aggSeriesName = 'age'
aggType = 'sum'
targetName = 'aggregated'

bla = vertices.selectExpr('{}({}) as {}'.format(aggType, aggSeriesName, targetName))
bla.show()
```

Output:

```
+----------+
|aggregated|
+----------+
|       257|
+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you.  I changed the title to clarify what I am asking.  I will leave this open for a few more days to see if anyone else has a solution.  I don't want to have to do the .withColumnRenamed(name_to_be_Changed,'aggregated') solution if I don't have to.  Maybe it's OCD, but it is ugly to me.